# Entity Framework - N para N, limpar lista

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

```
public class Aluno
{
    public int AlunoID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Turma> Turmas { get; set; }
}

public class Turma
{
    public int TurmaID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Aluno> Alunos { get; set; }
}
```

Um aluno já pertence a uma série de turmas, então quero que o aluno não pertença a nenhuma turma.

Tentei:

```
var bdAluno = new AlunoRepositorioEF(contexto);
var aluno = bdAluno.Get(x => x.AlunoID == ID).FirstOrDefault();
//aluno.Turmas = null; //Tentei este jeito também.
aluno.Turmas = new List<Turma>();
bdAluno.Atualizar(aluno);
bdAluno.SalvarTodos();
```

Porém ele não faz nada, mantém os relacionamentos.

```
public void Atualizar(TEntity obj)
{
    ctx.Entry<TEntity>(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;            
}

public void SalvarTodos()
{
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Contexto:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Aluno>()
            .HasMany(t=>t.Turmas)
            .WithMany(a => a.Alunos)
            .Map(m => m.MapLeftKey("Aluno_AlunoID")
            .MapRightKey("Turma_TurmaID")
            .ToTable("Area_Cursos_TurmaAluno"));
```

Comment: Um `foreach` nas turmas do aluno deletando a turma talvez funcione.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente isso resolva seu problema:

```
var bdAluno = new AlunoRepositorioEF(contexto);
var aluno = bdAluno.Get(x => x.AlunoID == ID).FirstOrDefault();

aluno.Turmas.Clear();
bdAluno.Atualizar(aluno);
bdAluno.SalvarTodos();
```

---

### Estendendo um pouco mais o assunto

Para ambos os casos, você precisa carregar as Turmas. Creio que isso você já faça diretamente ou por meio de *Lazy Loading*.

Pelo o vi em sua questão, você está com um repositório de objetos e quer deletar as turmas do usuário pelo repositório do aluno.

O padrão repository, pelo o que entendi, permite você mais de um tipo de coleção de objetos porque ele atende à um contexto de negócio (apesar de não ser essa a questão ainda).

Você pode ainda implementar métodos específicos para cada repositório, de acordo com a necessidade.

Como exemplo, e baseando no seu padrão do repositório, diria que você tem algo assim:

```
public class AlunoRepositorioEF : Repositorio<AppContext, Aluno>
{
    public AlunoRepositorioEF(AppContext context) { 
        _context = context;
    }
    ...
}
```

Bastaria adicionar um método para remover as turmas:

```
public void RemoverTurmas(int id)
{
    var aluno = Get(x => x.AlunoID == ID).FirstOrDefault();
    aluno.Turmas.Clear();
}
```

Então:

```
var bdAluno = new AlunoRepositorioEF(contexto);
dbAluno.RemoverTurmas(id);
```

---

**Também**, em cada repositório você pode ter uma interface do mesmo para adicionar métodos a mais que são necessários para aquele contexto de negócio.

Por exemplo:

```
public interface IAlunoRepositorioEF 
{
    void RemoverTurmas(int id);
}

public class AlunoRepositorioEF : IAlunoRepositorioEF, Repositorio<AppContext, Aluno>
{
    public AlunoRepositorioEF(AppContext context) { 
        _context = context;
    }
    ...

    public void RemoverTurmas(int id)
    {
        var aluno = Get(x => x.AlunoID == ID).FirstOrDefault();
        aluno.Turmas.Clear();
    }
}
```

---

### Edição

Mudei para o método `Clear()`, conforme você disse nos comentários.

Comment: O meu aluno.Turmas não tem o método RemoveAll, tem apenas o Remove. (Que funcionou para deletar uma turma)

Comment: Achei o método Clear, funciona igual.

Comment: Outra questão é: é realmente necessário a criação de uma Interface para estar implementando este método? Não poderia apenas adicionar no AlunoRepositorioEF sem a implementação de uma interface?